# Javascript range loses whitespace on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, range

[My code is here on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvOpNY)

I am trying to count the characters and wrap those that exceed a certain limit in a `<span>` which I've styled as red.

The code mostly works with the exception of the function that moves the caret to the end, on Firefox the ranges I create there lose all their whitespaces so that 'abcd abcd' becomes 'abcdabcd'

Here is the code for the function:

```
function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
        && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        // Modern browsers
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.collapse(false);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        // IE
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}
```

Has anybody faced this before and found a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox is ignoring white spaces in HTML. You have to modify it to replace space characters with   html escape characters. In place of the code

`inputText.substring(0,maxCharacter)`

You should do

`inputText.substring(0,maxCharacter).replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;')`

Similarly in place of code

`inputText.substring(maxCharacter)`

You should do

`inputText.substring(maxCharacter).replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;')`

That will fix it. Hopefully it will work in all other browsers too.

Changed pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgXBjp